# Prevent line break in header

Tags: html, css, sass

I have an h1 with line breaks. On mobile devices, there should be no line breaks.

This code works on Chrome and iPhone but not on Firefox. So I am afraid it might not work on all devices/browsers.

(The code snippet seems to ignore the media query).

```css
h1 {
  text-align: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 839px) {
 h1 {
  br {
   content: "";
   &:after {
    content: " ";
   }
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<h1>This is a<br>header<br>with line breaks</h1>
```

Note the spaces which get inserted by CSS when the header is on 1 line. And also the header should be able to align to right.
How could I make this cross-browser compatible?

Comment: So you want explicit line breaks that are only enforced when the screen is a certain size?

Comment: Yep the editor can insert line breaks in an header. But on smaller screen this should be ignored and breaks replaced for spaces to prevent sticking words together.

Comment: I can't find a way that I would be comfortable using. This is a fairly common question, but relying on a pseudo-element for `br` does not seem to be reliable (as you've already found). Is it possible to just clean this up on the server? For example, wrapping the text fragments in `span` would give you much more control when displaying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up following the advice of Tim Medora (thanks!).
Pseudo elements on br are not crossbrowser, for example FF and iE will not respond.

I adjusted my CMS (I built a PHP viewHelper in TYPO3) which converts linebreaks to spans.

```
$textBreakParts = explode("\n", $text);
$convertedText = "<span>".implode('</span> <span>', $textBreakParts)."</span>";
```

In SASS:

```
h1 span {display: block}

@media screen and (max-width: 839px) {
    h1 {
        span {
            display: inline;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you leave the header normally spaced and put the `<br>` after each word you want it to break at, a space will be left to the left side of each line which is okay since you want it to be aligned to the right. Then add `display:none` on the `<br>` at the proper screen size.

```css
h1 {
  text-align: right;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 839px) {
 h1 br{
      display:none;
    } 
}
```

```html
<h1>This is a<br> header<br> with line breaks</h1>
```

Comment: This indeed works, however now I need to educate my editors to never forget to put spaces at the start of a new line..